# Understanding decision boundary of logistic regression

Tags: logistic, python, optimization, gradient-descent

I am currently attempting to code out a simple example of logistic regression to better understand the concept behind it. I generated the following classification example:

[image: Classification example]

The code I use to optimise my decision boundary is the gradient descent algorithm which I implemented like this:

```
def gradient_descent_iterate(alpha, x, y, ep, max_iter):

    # Set-up of variables
    converged = False
    iter = 0
    m = x.shape[0]
    t0 = np.random.random(x.shape[1])
    t1 = np.random.random(x.shape[1])

    # Calculate the cost
    J = -(1/m)*sum([(-y[i]*log(1/(1+exp(t0 + t1*x[i]))) + (1-y[i])*log(1-(1/(1+exp(t0 + t1*x[i]))))) for i in range(m)])

    # Calculate and update the gradient
    while(not converged):
        # for each iteration, compute the gradient
        grad0 = (1/m) * sum([(t0 + t1*x[i] - y[i]) for i in range(m)])
        grad1 = (1/m) * sum([(t0 + t1*x[i] - y[i])*x[i] for i in range(m)])
        # Save to temp
        temp0 = t0 - alpha*grad0
        temp1 = t1 - alpha*grad1
        # Update theta
        t0 = temp0
        t1 = temp1

        #Calculate MSE in each iteration
        e = (1/2*m)*sum([(t0 + t1*x[i] - y[i])**2 for i in range(m)])
        #Check for early convergence
        if(abs(J-e)<=ep):
            print('Optimizer has converged, iterations',iter,'!')
            converged = True
        #Update error
        J = e
        iter = iter+1
        #End algorithm after max_iter iterations
        if (iter == max_iter):
            print('Maximum iterations exceeded')
            converged = True
    return t0, t1
```

Which outputs soon after:

```
Optimizer has converged, iterations 200 !
Theta0 =  [ 0.46931187] , Theta1 =  [ 0.44905758]
```

My biggest problem is now to understand what exactly this tells me. I understood that the decision boundary is used to return h(x)>0 or h(x)<0 depending if the label is 1 or 0. Here, when I am substituting values from either label, I don't receive this classification.

```
0.46931187 + 0.44905758 * -0.4708 = 0.2  which is not <0
```

Nevertheless, when plotting I still get the following classifier, which looks okay to me:

[image: Classification]

Comment: Right now, your query is couched in terms of declarative statements. I think you need to articulate a clear question.

Comment: Okay. Assuming that my calculated values for theta are correct, how does this create a decision boundary that correctly classifies my data. Right now, all points, no matter if in the 0 or 1 class, return a value >0.

Comment: Use of the word 'correctly' implies an *a priori* theoretical decision boundary, does it not? Rules of thumb are usually employed in lieu of this including partitioning the predicted values at their median to produce a 50-50 split. Other approaches are possible, e.g., a grid search, empirically- or data-driven method in an effort at finding the minimum classification error between predicted (the focus of the grid search) and actual values. The *grid search* could range from an arbitrary low value, incrementing the predicted values by 1% up to a max value as a function of the data.

Comment: **It looks like what you are doing is *a linear fit*** 

Note that you are minimizing 

$$e=\sum (\theta_1+\theta_2x_i-y_i)^2$$ 

using the gradient of $e$

$$\begin{array}\\
\frac{\partial e}{\partial \theta_1} &= \sum2(\theta_1+t_2x_i-y_i)  \\\frac{\partial e}{\partial \theta_2} &= \sum2(\theta_1+\theta_2x_i-y_i)x_i\end{array}$$

this is different from your initially defined `J = -(1/m)*sum([(-y[i]*log(1/(1+exp(t0 + t1*x[i]))) + (1-y[i])*log(1-(1/(1+exp(t0 + t1*x[i]))))) for i in range(m)])
`

Comment: Regarding your questions about the h(x) stuff it is unclear what you are doing. While this is partly because of my lack of experience with python and variables/functions as `shape[]` or `make_classification()`, your problem is not stated with a *complete* test case making it hard to follow/get your question (Just one example: one might try to track what happened with "theta0 = ..." and will not be able to follow the trail because you do not show how and where this line is printed.). also you do not introduce what kind of classification you are doing and how your data looks like (what is y?).